# Python: recognize word, capture following number

Tags: python, regex, string

I am trying to use RegEx to scan thru an email, recognize the word `package`, and then capture the next number that follows.

For example, in the body of one email there is this line:

`NEFS 8 has a PACKAGE DEAL see below valued at $55,000.00 call if interested.`

The code I am trying to accomplish this task with is:

```
word = ['package']
package_re = re.compile(r'({}).*?([\d,]+)'.format('|'.join(word)), re.IGNORECASE|re.MULTILINE|re.DOTALL)

with open(file_path) as f:
    for line in f:
        for match in package_re.finditer(f.read()):
            print("yessssssssssssss")
            price = match.group()
            print(price)
```

but it fails to even print "yessssssssssssss" so that means the RegEx itself is failing...

I was under the impression a RegEx like this is supposed to capture anything in the list `word`, for example, and then `.*?` will capture everything up until the next match, which is a number given by `[\d,]+`.

Any help solving this problem, which I feel is a pretty simple problem, is appreciated. Thanks.

How the email appears when opened with Thunderbird:

[image]

How it appears when saved and opened as a txt.file (this is the version that my code runs on btw):

[image]

Comment: What's the use of 'package' keyword exactly? Why don't you search a `$` sign followed by numbers for example?

Comment: `f.read()` should be `line`. You're already reading the file by iterating it. No need to read it again.

Comment: Does your regular expression work in the interactive prompt?

Comment: @errata I don't use the `$` as a search because in other emails the `$` is elsewhere. The only time I want the RegEx to capture a number is if it follows the word `package`

Comment: @PeterWood changing `f.read()` to `f.line()` resulted in an error: `AttributeError: '_io.TextIOWrapper' object has no attribute 'line'`

Comment: I don't understand do you need just a number in the end or everything after the word "package"?

Comment: Just the first number that follows the word `package`. Sorry if that was unclear :(

Comment: @theprowler I didn't say to put `f.line()`.

Comment: Ohhh my bad. Changing it to line didn't change the printout either

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your loop. And you need to select the correct group

```
word = ['package']
package_re = re.compile(r'({}).*?([\d,]+)'.format('|'.join(word)), re.I|re.M|re.S|re.U)

with open(file_path) as f:
    for match in package_re.finditer(f.read()):
        print("yessssssssssssss")
        price = match.group(2)
        print(price)
```

Comment: Making that change didn't alter the printout at all.

Comment: Maybe at the encoding flag (re.UNICODE) because it works with the string you provided

Comment: That also didn't work :(   it's not even printing `yessssssssss` so that means it's not even matching right? So it must be something wrong with the RegEx ?

Comment: @theprowler Tobey's example works for me... Just to point out that your regex should be `r'({}).*?([\d,]+)'` if you want to capture decimals too...

Comment: hmn maybe.  copy the content of your file to https://regex101.com/ save it and share the link. That way we can test the regex properly

Comment: Well now combining everything from these comments: I lined it up like you said, I changed `f.read()` to `line` like the guy above said, and I actually left the `match.group()` as is, and now it prints the price as `ect: FW: NEFS 8`. That's not a typo btw, that's what it prints out. I don't even see that appearing anywhere. Also, doing `match.group(2)` simply changes the printout to `8`.

Comment: using group() with no args prints the whole match (i.e. group(0)), group(n) prints the nth group match (i.e stuff in brackets in your regex ). from you regex .. the number group in the 2nd group. without without lookin at a snippet of you file.. i can be much help. post it to regex101. you can save it and share it

Comment: My only hesitation to posting the entire email is that it's got a lot of names and emails in it, but I'll just delete those out and post the main body of it. I'm really confused why even doing something as simple as `if 'package' in line: print(line)` fails to print the line that the word `package` is on. But ok I'll upload it to regex101 now

Comment: I'll also edit into my question how the email appears when I open it in the Thunderbird window and how it looks when saved as a txt.file

Comment: And here's the link to my RegEx file, but idk how to also write in that piece in my code `word = ('package')` since that isn't in the RegEx itself (https://regex101.com/r/ZfZTVv/1)

Comment: I honestly am so confused. My RegEx is LITERALLY exactly the same as yours, run on the same snippet, and it doesn't capture anything. Am I doing something wrong? https://regex101.com/r/ZfZTVv/4/